# Create unique identifier that is displayed to the user and admin via Ninja Forms

Tags: plugins, plugin-ninja-forms

I'm trying to source documentation on how to create a unique identifier that can be displayed to the user after form submission and to the admin that also receives the submission.

1. User submits form
2. User receives confirmation email with "Your code is 2290"
3. Admin receives form confirmation "User has signed up with order X and code 2290"

I've found a way to grab sequential numbering from the order of submission but it needs to be a unique code to that specific user

The only thing I thought would be to add some sort of relay of their IP and name

Something like Hashids can convert their IP into a small unique identifier but I'm really unsure how to implement something this complex and would need something simple that I've overlooked that ninja forms allows/provides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code into theme's functions.php: ( for Ninja Forms 2.9.x )

```
function unique_code_submission( $data, $field_id ) {
    global $uniqueCode;

    if ( "string" !== gettype( $uniqueCode ) )
        $uniqueCode = uniqid();

    /* here goes your code to populate a field */

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_field', 'unique_code_submission', 10, 2 );
```

Within above function you will have a unique, 13 characters long code in `$uniqueCode` global variable. This code will be generated once only, when the filter is triggered first time. More information about `ninja_forms_field`filter: [here](http://docs.ninjaforms.com/customer/portal/articles/1981032-filters-ninja_forms_field).

**UPDATE:** for Ninja Forms 3.0 and up:

```
function unique_code_submission( $fields ) {
    $uniqueCode = uniqid();

    /*  here goes your code to populate a field. For example:
        let's populate hidden field, which has key value of
        'hidden_1492812363939' */

    $index = 0;
    while ( 0 <= $index ) {
        ++$index;
        if ( 'hidden_1492812363939' == $fields[ $index-1 ][ 'key' ] ) {
            $fields[ $index-1 ][ 'value' ] = $uniqueCode;
            $index = -1;
        }
    }

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_display_fields', 'unique_code_submission', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for that! How did you output a 13 digit code from the unique code? Is there a way to change the digit length? I need a 3-6 digit code

Comment: @Tom: If you make the code shorter, it cannot be guaranteed to be unique. Tell me, which version of Ninja Forms, you have. Is it a paid version? With this info, I'll be able to provide better help.

Comment: Yes it's the paid version and the latest one. I'm using it as a system of payment confirmation - User is given code, code given to me as confirmation of payment and identification

Comment: if you didn't get the above

Comment: @Tom: I've got a new hook to use, which is valid for your version of Ninja Forms. Could you email me ( fpw (at) fw2s.com ) your exported form, so I can work on it, and send it back to you with instructions?

Comment: I paste the 3.0 code in my themes functions and it actually stops the entire theme from loading. It must be causing it to loop or something as it's not actually loading the website content due to those functions

Have you tested the 3.0 ver above?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, and it works. Verbatim pasting of my code, would not work, as values used there are not from your form but mine. Again, export your form and email it to me ( fpw (at) fw2s.com ). I'll send it back to you corrected, and with further instructions, how to use it.

Comment: our message couldn't be delivered because the recipient's email server (outside Office 365) rejected it because it couldn't determine if your message is coming from a location that is associated with your email domain. This is a security measure commonly done to help prevent malicious email or spam email from entering the recipient's email system. 

Can't email you

Comment: Send it to frankpw@shaw.ca then.

Comment: I can confirm, this still works in 2021! Excellent example. If you are looking to use the code, simply change the hidden ID to reflect the one you have in your form and place the remainder code in your functions.php.